# create instance of class after installing package with composer - PHP

Tags: php, oop

I just used composer to install [Highcharts](https://github.com/ghunti/HighchartsPHP). after installing the package i have this path in my project, to lead to the file where the class `Highcharts` defined:
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myapp/vendor/ghunti/highcharts-php/src/Highchart.php`

so as i;m doing with other classes in my project i added this line in the beginning of my file:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myapp/vendor/ghunti/highcharts-php/src/Highchart.php");
```

but when i try to create instance of this class, like:

```
$chart = new Highchart();
```

in my file i get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Highchart' not found in ...
```

any idea what am i doing wrong? thx

Comment: There's a namespace in `Highchart.php`

Comment: with composer, why don't you require the `autoload.php` instead of the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
use Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart;
```

before `new Highchart();`

It may be usefull to take a look at [official demos from the GitHub repository](https://github.com/ghunti/HighchartsPHP/tree/master/demos) of the **Highchart** library.